# How to handle new line to a single paragraph python docx

Tags: python, parsing, docx, python-docx

I have a problem when extracting the .docx file from Microsoft Word. I want to handle the data extracted by using python-docx library. When I want to scrap the file. I have a problem that a single paragraph turns into multiple paragraphs, but on my document file, I set it as a single paragraph with Bold text.

This is my script

```
import io
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd
# import win32com.client
import docx2txt
from docx import Document

industri_minuman = "test.docx"

for idx, para in enumerate(doc_industri_minuman.paragraphs):
    for run in para.runs:
        print(run.text)
```

This is the result from script

```
AGA, AMDK / INTAN MULIA, CV
Produk Utama: Air Mineral Aga
Tenaga Kerja: 20 - 99 Orang
Telepon: 82242000000
Email: -
Alamat Pabrik: 
Ds
 
Gunungsari
 
Ds
 
Sumbergondo
,
Kec
 
Glenmore
 Kab Banyuwangi
```

Expected Result:

```
AGA, AMDK / INTAN MULIA, CV
Produk Utama: Air Mineral Aga
Tenaga Kerja: 20 - 99 Orang
Telepon: 82242000000
Email: -
Alamat Pabrik: Ds Gunungsari Ds Sumbergondo,
Kec Glenmore Kab Banyuwangi
```

This is my attached of document file

[Link to Docs File](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DIvqWsYRrzjGpTxz1lNxlOIaMYTM3jdu/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117792607172387398524&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 1):

MS Word paragraphs are a little unpredictable, mainly because of the style. If you unzip a docx file and navigate to the content, we'll se a lot of tags like <w:r>, which is how MS Word handles the different styles in the doc.

A few days ago I develop a library that replaces text inside a document, and to do this I had to do some "magic" because of these breaks you mentioned. If you are interested, take a look here: https://github.com/ivanbicalho/python-docx-replace

Comment: Well thanks for the response, I've tried your library with this cmd `docx_replace(doc_industri_minuman, key="<w:r>", val="")` But when I load it agaIn, it didn't change, it still got a break paragraf.

Comment: Oh, this library is focused on replacing text inside the document and it requires the following format: ${}, that means, if there is a paragraph in your document like: "Hello ${name}, how are you?", after calling the method `docx_replace(doc, name="Ivan")`, you'll get: "Hello Ivan, how are you?". Your problem is a little different, I don't know if you'll be able to get your paragraphs like you mentioned. Why is this necessary? Maybe you can find another solution.